# Not able to submit image on http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/

Tags: support, status-completed, featured-photo, reputation

meta.photo.stackexchange.com say that I should have atleast 5 reputation to Submit a pic for hall of fame.

Now I have 5 Reputation. Still I am not able to?
Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've posted an image, so I assume it took some time for the system to adjust your reputation?  But looks resolved now.

Comment: Yeah After long time I got that Link to Ans that question.
Thanks for the look up by the way :D